# Is it worth to resize a List in C#?

Tags: c#, list

I am intending to use a List in my C# program. 
Now, everytime I call a function `makeTemplate` the contents as well as the size of the list will change. I was thinking of resizing the list (haven't thought of how to do this yet, I heard AddRange might be ok for this) but then I thought, why not just *create another* list, abandon the previous one and let the GC deal with that. 
Something along these lines

```
class aClass
{
   private List<float> template;

   public ivoid makeTemplate(size)
   {
      //Here I abandon the previous template hold in some memory and 
      //get some new list
     template= new List<float>(size);
     //.....
   }

}
```

I am thinking it is better this way, Any opinion on this? 
(I imagine that in C++ I will have to check if it is null and delete the memory before doing this)

Comment: just out of curiosity, why would you want to resize a `List`? Isn't it perfect as it is. If you want to abandon the old `List` items, can't you simply call `template.Clear();` to clear the old data.

Comment: The template size (which is contained in the list) can have any size, determined by the user

Comment: Just set size one time, to the maximum expected number of items. List size is not like array. `foreach` will not iterate "empty slots". The size is there only for performance. So, list doesn't resize later, when you add more items. Even if you size it too small, it will resize itself to bigger. You need no worry about it.

Comment: Your new list, is it a **completely** new list? Or is it the original list with some extra entries? Can you update your post to include some sample 'before and after' data?

Comment: @mjwills It is a completely new list.

Comment: In that case, I would just do what you are doing (i.e. `new` up a new one). _Or `Clear` the old one._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list will resize its buffer automatically, so there's no point in creating a new list and throwing away the old one. You can set the list capacity if you know the final size in advance--this will save memory by making the buffer only as big as you need. It will also save CPU time if the increase in size is so dramatic that it involves multiple resize/copy operations--your code will only need one operation.

The C# `List` class works almost the same as a C++ `vector`, if you're more familiar with C++. In each, the buffer is doubled each time it increases.

`AddRange` automatically increases the list size to the right number, instead of potentially increasing more than once during your addition of elements as it would do if you add one-by-one.

So in short, don't worry about it, use `AddRange` if it's equally convenient, and set the list capacity if you know it in advance.

If you want to see the C# source, these are the most important classes for analyzing the performance of containers: [Enumerable](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs), [List](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs).

Comment: So instead of creating a new list, I would do 'template.Capacity=newSize;' and then 'template.Clear();' ?

Comment: @KansaiRobot Yes, that's what you'd do if it's semantically okay to be using the same list. Create a new one if there are still references to the old list that wouldn't appreciate their data being erased.

Comment: @KansaiRobot - You need to ensure that you don't try to set the capacity to a value less than the current count in the list otherwise you'll get a `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. You need to do the `.Clear()` first if that's the case.